# How much time it takes if we just update some description or screenshot of app when its already live on App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

How much time it takes if we just update some description or screenshot of app when its already live on App Store ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to submit a new app version, only after that new changes will go live.